# Get Response Headers in Restangular getList

Tags: pagination, restangular

my Rails API wites pagination data in the response headers in this way:

```
X-Pagination {"total":332,"total_pages":12,"first_page":true,"last_page":false,"previous_page":null,"next_page":2,"out_of_bounds":false,"offset":0}
```

I need to access this value during a getList() call in order to display paginator and so on.

I've seen that the headers are empty.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks, Stefano

Comment: do you want to set it to header?

Answer (score 9):

You can use [setFullResponse](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#setfullresponse) method it will return all response data. I suppose you need a full response as an exception so just configure Restangular locally like:

```
var rest = Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {
    RestangularConfigurer.setFullResponse(true);
});
rest.getList().then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.headers('X-Pagination'));
});
```

Comment: it think it's important to mention here that you should provide `Access-Control-Expose-Headers:` from server

Answer (score 4):

To add on 2j2e's answer, i've created a factory and I use that like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('RestFullResponse', ['Restangular', function (Restangular) {
    return Restangular.withConfig(function (RestangularConfigurer) {
      RestangularConfigurer.setFullResponse(true);
    });
  }]);
```

And in the controller:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('PikachuCtrl', function ($scope, Restangular, RestFullResponse) {

    var ideas = RestFullResponse.all('Pikachus');

    ideas.getList().then(function(response){
          $scope.Pikachus = response.data;
          var XPagination = response.headers('X-Pagination');
        };
})
```

Comment: variable name with dash??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read only particular headers of the response and you don't need full responses with header in all Restangular requests, you can look for the header in the [response interceptor](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#addresponseinterceptor) and add it to the response.

```
app.config(function(RestangularProvider) {
  RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor(function(data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {
    var pagination;
    if (pagination = response.headers('X-Pagination')) {
      data.paginationData= pagination;
    }
    return data;
  });
});
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Returns null even though I can see the header in the Chrome Dev console.